# How to append colors alternatives to divs using for loop as Zebra using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi all iam working on jquery I need to add colors to the `divs alternatively` as `zebra` here i had worked i got the appending color `virtically` but i need to make it `horizontally` also here i need to apply `forloop` condition to apply colors if i click the `vZebra button` it should apply colors verticlly if i click the HZebra `button` colors should appy horizontally with if condition here my worked jsfiddle you can check can any body help me to do this work thanks in advance

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP6UF/18/)

Comment: you need to change the layout of the HTML, this will make things work for you, like main div which holds child div for rows and rows div will hold divs for each cells. try it! and then use even odd for horizontal using same logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP6UF/49/). Hope this helps. The horizontal `divs` are being wrapped inside another container.

Answer (score 0):

why not wrap each row in a div, then you can use the :odd selector on the rows and you can use the :odd selector per div in each row...